# How can I cross-compile using CMake, clang and standard library from source

Tags: cmake, clang, cross-compiling

I am trying to use clang to cross-compile for a bare-metal system where my host standard library is unsuitable (my host is AArch64, my target is thumbv7em-none-eabihf). At the moment, trying to compile any CMake project fails with errors along the lines of:

```
ld.lld: error: unable to find library -lc
ld.lld: error: unable to find library -lm
```

I gather this is because clang/LLVM, unlike the ARM GNU toolchain, does not provide a standard library for the target. I also get the error:

```
ld.lld: error: unable to find library -lclang_rt.builtins-thumbv7em
```

Which I am not sure the source of.

I don't want to use the ARM GNU toolchain's standard library implementation. Instead, I would like to include picolibc as a sub-project. I have tried doing this by including the [picolibc source](https://github.com/picolibc/picolibc) in the project and using `add_subdirectory` (I think I don't need to include `target_link_libraries` as picolibc adds the default `c` target but please correct me if I am wrong). When trying to compile picolibc however, the compiler checks fail again, because they still have a dependency on the standard library, even when the project you are trying to compile does not! Is there some way around this? I have seen setting `CMAKE_C_COMPILER_FORCED` and `CMAKE_C_COMPILER_WORKS` recommended online, but these seem to be deprecated or internal, and I have had mixed results.

Here is my minimal CMake toolchain:

```
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Generic)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR arm)
set(TOOLCHAIN thumbv7em-none-eabihf)

set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER clang)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER clang++)
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} --target=${TOOLCHAIN}")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} --target=${TOOLCHAIN}")
```